# git -diff to also show commit message

Tags: git, git-diff

I currently have something like this in my code:

```
git_cmd = 'git diff --name-only %s...HEAD %s' % (options.commit_id, options.path)
proc = subprocess.Popen(git_cmd,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
changed_files = proc.communicate()
```

It pulls what files have been changed or added between a certain commit and current date. I would also like to know what commit messages were assigned to every change.

Answer (score 2):

You need `git log` instead of `git diff`:

```
git log --name-only %s...HEAD %s
```

Comment: Yes, but it's worth noting that `git diff` treats the three-dot syntax specially. Depending on the situation, they may want `--right-only` for this (and maybe `--boundary` or other cleverness).

Comment: i actually ran git log on every file received in a loop. Thanks for the info

Answer (score -2):

So i made another command using git log. My code already tabled all the files from git using gid diff, now for every of these files i used

```
 git log --follow
```

, allowing me to easyli get the commit messages associated with every file.